# Stream over embeddable java class

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an embeddable class with entity

```
@Embeddable
public class EventId implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Date updateDateTime;
}

@Entity
public class Event {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EventId id;
    private String name;

}
```

How to get below map of EventId.id(Long),Event from steam for given event list

```
List<Event> events;
Map<Long, Event> eventMap = events.stream... ?
```

Comment: What values shall the key in the map have? Did you try anything yourself? What approach would you take if you would use "traditional" loops?

Comment: https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/

Comment: What exactly is `@Embeddable`?

Comment: @cyberbrain Updated question for key, it is id of embeddable class

Comment: @BasilBourque definition of emeddable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143707/what-is-difference-between-entity-and-embeddable

Comment: Add tags for the frameworks in question.

Comment: The annotations are really superfluous to the question. I would take them out of the example.

Comment: I think that you want to process data in memory that should rather be processed by the database. Try to write a query that provides you with that data, especially when you have to process multiple events this will probably lead to better performance and save you some Java heap space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your purpose is to sort  `List<Event> events` by EventId.id so you can use  `Collectors.groupingBy` like this：

```
Map<Long, List<Event>> collect = events.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event -> Event.getId().getId()));
```